# AutoRefresh Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a module which I use to check what color the cell contains. If the cell is red, blue or green. But when I use the function: `=SumBycolor(cell with colorx;From cell:toCell)` it doesn't auto update. I have to open the cell and press enter to make any updates
Anyone have some good tips for how to add auto update?

```
Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, rRange As Range)
    Dim cSum As Long
    Dim ColIndex As Integer

    ColIndex = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex
     For Each cl In rRange
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColIndex Then
        cSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cl, cSum)
      End If
     Next cl

    SumByColor = cSum
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Function
```

Comment: Try adding `Application.Volatile` at the top of your code.

Comment: @MattCremeens has a good idea here.  Make sure you put that after the `Function SumByColor...` line of code.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try. But the funny thing is: if i Color the cell first then put in example 10. it update but not the other way around.

Comment: Updating cell colours does not cause a recalculation - even using `Application.Volatile` won't correct that (though it will make your function recalculate once the workbook does for any other reason). You'd be far better off colouring the cell based on some data and using that data in your sum/count function.

Comment: @Rory, How can i change the code to do that? or can i use the code i alredy have?

Comment: Use conditional formatting to colour the cells based on the contents (or a formula) and then use that data to count/sum, not the colour.

Comment: @rory Have any exaples on how to do that:)? kind of new with excel vba:S

Comment: I'm not talking about VBA at all. If you use cell data, with conditional formatting to colour the cells, then you can use simple SUMIF formulas instead of UDFs.

Comment: @Rory got it, and it works:) but i got a nother problem. Big issue.The excel workbook is big, and have alot of cells. if i press- Search and find -> Replace i find 1.3 Million cells. I have turned of Auto calculation. I can se that alot of emby cells has this $A$1..... Is there any way to reduce the amout of active cells.

Comment: No idea what you mean, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in sheet1 then go to event of that sheet and select Worksheet_SelectionChange and write Sheet1.Calculate. This will calculate the function when ever selection is changed. so you do not have to open the cell and press enter to make any updates. Updates will happen with change in selection.

Paste the following code in sheet code where the formula is kept

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

sheets("data").calculate
End Sub

Comment: i Have 2 sheets, and the formula is a module, how do you do that?The name of my sheet is "Mal"

Comment: Seems like i got an error on Sheets("Mal").Calculate

Comment: I understand that formula is in module. But you might be using that formula in a perticular sheet using "=SumByColor(a1,a2)". Type  sheets("abc").calculate in the code window of this sheet.select Worksheet_SelectionChange in event of this sheet. If you are still getting error then please tell me what is the error that u are getting.

Comment: Hi havent had the chanse to work with this for now. in my worksheet "Mal". i have the following code.

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Sheets("Mal").Calculate

End Sub

Still dosent update.

If i color the cell RED: and enter number 12. If i then change the color to Green it dosent update. I have to open the cell where the forumal is, and press enter. then it updated taht is 12 in green.